# How can I mount a directory of the host system for use inside a FreeBSD jail?

Tags: mount, directory, freebsd, chroot, jails

I am performing the following on FreeBSD 9.0-STABLE:

```
mount_nullfs /foo /jail/foo
```

After that, from *within* the host system, the mount works. So this works:

```
touch /foo/bar && ls /jail/foo/bar
```

But when I change into the jail the mounted directory is empty:

```
jexec 1 tcsh
ls /foo/bar
```

I get:

```
ls: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
```

`/foo` is completely empty.

How can I have the files in the mounted directory show up correctly when mounted inside the chroot as found in the host system?

Comment: Did you restart the jail after mounting the nullfs?

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that I had mounted onto a directory which itself is already rebound (mounted via nullfs).

```
/var/data/home/j/mroot on /var/data/home/j/www
/var/data/home/js/www on /var/data/home/j/www/s
/foo on /var/data/home/js/www/foo
```

Besides being confusing this is apparently unsupported / wrong.

I changed it like so (note the path in the last line):

```
/var/data/home/j/mroot on /var/data/home/j/www
/var/data/home/js/www on /var/data/home/j/www/s
/foo on /var/data/home/j/www/s/foo
```

Now the mount works without any additional settings.